# Golang http web server stops responding to http requests and sending out "200" response after continuously running for about 12 hours

Tags: go, webserver

Golang http web server (listening on port :8000) stops responding to http requests and sending out "200" response after continuously running for about 12 hours. After examining the node where the web server is running and performing netstat; following is seen: Could this be because of TCP connections not getting correctly closed by the server program as there are lot of CLOSE_WAIT connections for the "myserver" process as seen below. Also, after this issue happens a localhost curl to port 8000 hangs and does not return a "200" response. Any pointers on what could be happening here ? Thanks!

```
# netstat -alpn | grep -i 8000     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60502         127.0.0.1:8000          TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp6       1      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      20987/myserver       
tcp6       1      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:38436    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver      
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32800    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6      91      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:42204    ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:46250    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:44042    ESTABLISHED 20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:40876    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32774    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32792    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:33088    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6      92      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:39122    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32788    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32768    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:38262    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32790    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32772    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32776    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:34102    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:38872    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32798    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32786    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:46248    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:38430    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:39092    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:38866    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:34126    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6      91      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32768    ESTABLISHED 20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:38246    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:45316    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:45328    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32782    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      0 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32794    CLOSE_WAIT  20987/myserver       
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:32772    LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      1 100.10.10.2:8000    200.10.10.2:33078    LAST_ACK    -
```

The server code is very simple as follows and 1 http request comes to the web server every 5 seconds and the server replies back with a "200":

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/", taskHandler)

// New method to start a customized server with timeouts
myServer := &http.Server{
    Addr:         ":8000",
    Handler:      mux,
    ReadTimeout:  3 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 3 * time.Second,
}
// Here we will disable keep alives for the server connections
myServer.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)
if err = myServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("server failed to start %v", err)
}
```

The following is the task handler code:

```
func taskHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        response := "200"
        value := getSomeDBValue()
        if value == "0" {
            log.Info("Response sent back -> %s", response)
            io.WriteString(w, response)
        }
    }
```